# How do I find the following probabilities? (The details are below)

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

An auto store has two suppliers for a given part. The store orders from Supplier A 70% of the time, and supplier B 30% of the time. Supplier A's parts are defective with probability 0.02, and supplier B's parts are defective with probability 0.05.

a. If I buy a part, what is the probability that it is defective?

b. I buy a part and it is defective. What is the probability that it comes from Supplier A?

c. Let's assume that the parts arrive from the factory in boxes of 10; if I pick two parts from the same box then I know they are from the same factory (but I don't know which factory they are from). If I buy two parts from the same box, what is the probability that they are both defective? Hint: What is the probability that two parts from supplier A are both defective? How about two parts from supplier B?

Okay everyone, here's what I think the answers are:
for a, I multiply the defective probability by the percent I order from each supplier so I get

a. $0.7 \times 0.02 + 0.3 \times 0.05 = 0.029$

b. $(0.7 \times 0.02 + 0.3 \times 0.05) / 0.7$ . I know I need to find what percentage of defectiveness comes from Supplier A, I'm not sure I'm calculating this correctly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

c.  $(0.7 \times 0.02 + 0.3 \times 0.05 ) (0.7 \times 0.02 + 0.3 \times 0.05 ) = 0.000841$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Your calculation is correct.

b. 
$$
Pr(\text{from A}|\text{defective}) 
= \frac{Pr(\text{defective}|\text{from A})Pr(\text{from A})}{Pr(\text{defective})}
= \frac{0.02(0.7)}{0.029}
= \frac{14}{29}
= 0.4827586
$$

c.

$
Pr(\text{two parts are defective}|\text{the box is from A})
= 0.02^2
$

$
Pr(\text{two parts are defective}|\text{the box is from B})
= 0.05^2
$

$$
\begin{align}
&Pr(\text{two parts are defective})
\\ &= Pr(\text{two parts are defective}|\text{the box is from A})Pr(\text{the box is from A}) + Pr(\text{two parts are defective}|\text{the box is from B})Pr(\text{the box is from B})
\\ &= 0.02^2(0.7) + 0.05^2(0.3)
\\ &= 0.00103
\end{align}
$$